# Valor da variável parece não mudar de acordo com o loop

Tags: javascript, svg, eventos

Tenho um array e estou fazendo um loop. Dentro desse loop eu pego o tamanho total de itens de cada array e monto um evento `onmouseover` exibindo um tooltip com esses números. Mas quando passo o mouse em cima do elemento, ele só exibe um número para todos os elementos: **76 distribuidores**. Não exibe o valor de cada um. Agora se eu coloco um `console.log` abaixo da variável **total** ele me exibe todos os valores certinhos, mas quando é dentro do `onmouseover` ele me retorna igual. O código que tenho é:

```
setTimeout(function(){

        var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        .style("background", "#FFF");

        var GrupoPosicoesMapa = GeraPosicoesDistribuidores(Posicoes);

        if(GrupoPosicoesMapa != ''){

          for(indexGroup in GrupoPosicoesMapa){

            //var indexArray = randFunction(0, sizeof(GrupoPosicoesMapa[indexGroup]));

            var ObjectGroup = GrupoPosicoesMapa[indexGroup][0];

            var total = GrupoPosicoesMapa[indexGroup].length;

            var circleSelection = group.append("circle")
                                              .attr('id', 'bolha')
                                              .attr('cx', ObjectGroup.x)
                                              .attr('cy', ObjectGroup.y)
                                              .attr('r', 5)
                                              .attr('stroke', 'gray')
                                              .attr('stroke-width', 1)
                                              .attr('fill', 'red')
                                              .on("mouseover", function(){

                                                      console.log('Total:', total);
                                                      return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
                                                      .style("padding", "10px")
                                                      .style("border", "1px solid #ccc")
                                                      .style("border-radius", "6px")
                                                      .html(total+' distribuidor(es)'); //alterado 6 = 1

                                                    })
                                                    .on("mousemove", function(){

                                                      return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px")
                                                      .style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");
                                                    })

                                                    .on("mouseout", function(){


                                                      return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
                                                })
                                                .on('click', function(){

                                                  // AbreModalDistribuidores(v.codigo_distribuidor);
                                                  // console.log(v.codigo_distribuidor);

                                                });

                var textSelection = circleSelection.append("text")
                                                 .attr('font-size', 16)
                                                 .attr('fill', 'white')
                                                 .attr('font-family', 'Arial')
                                                 .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                                                 .attr('alignment-baseline', 'baseline')
                                                 .attr('x', ObjectGroup.x + 1.5)
                                                 .attr('y', ObjectGroup.y + 6)
                                                 .text(total);

          }
        }

        }, 4000);
```

Comment: Você poderia colocar o que `GrupoPosicoesMapa` parece? Um `console.log(GrupoPosicoesMapa)` talvez?

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway ele é um array com um monete de objetos dentro. Os valores eles retornam tudo certinho. Se eu colocar um `console.log` em baixo de **total** ele aparecem a contagem certa, agora dentro do "mouseover" ele retorna o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que a variável `total` está sempre sendo declarada no escopo atual, não no bloco do `for... in` (e você sempre refere à mesma variável). Por exemplo, a linha:

```
var total = GrupoPosicoesMapa[indexGroup].length;
```

está re-definindo o valor da variável `total` que pertence ao escopo da função dada à `setTimeout()`, no topo.

Bom, como os eventos ocorrem logo depois do loop, o valor de `total` vai se referir ao último elemento da `Array` de `GrupoPosicoesMapa` (okay, isso também vai depender se o construtor do objeto herda `Array`).

Baseado no ES6, você pode declarar a variável `total` no bloco do `for... in` utilizando `const` ou `let` invés de `var`.

```
let total = GrupoPosicoesMapa[indexGroup].length;
```

No ECMAScript 3 ou ECMAScript 5 você pode expressar uma função no corpo ou bloco do `for... in` (porque a função vai gerar um escopo).

```
function handle(indexGroup) { /* Aqui fica o corpo do loop */ }

for (var k in GrupoPosicoesMapa) handle(k)
```